# Implementing a word-chain checker

Tags: java, beginner

This is web exercise 3.1.45. from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick & Wayne:

> Write a program that reads in a list of words from the command line
> and prints `true` if they form a word chain and `false` otherwise. In a
> word chain, adjacent words must differ in exactly one letter, e.g.,
> HEAL, HEAD, DEAD, DEED, DEER, BEER.

Here is my program:

```
public class WordChainChecker 
{
    public static boolean checkWordCouple(String word1, String word2)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int wordLength = word1.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
        {
            if (word1.charAt(i) != word2.charAt(i)) counter++;
        }
        if (counter > 1) return false;
        else             return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String word1 = StdIn.readString();
        String word2 = StdIn.readString();
        boolean truth = true && checkWordCouple(word1,word2);
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
        {
            word1 = StdIn.readString();
            truth = truth && checkWordCouple(word1,word2);
            word2 = word1; 
        }
        System.out.println(truth);
    }
}
```

[StdIn](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html) is a simple API written by the authors of the book. I checked my program and it works.

Is there any way that I can improve my program?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Requirements

### Number of words

Are you guaranteed to have at least 2 words?  If so, you could simplify your loop, by removing the first read; the loop will take care of the second & subsequent words:

```
    String word2 = StdIn.readString();
    boolean truth = true;
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
    {
        String word1 = StdIn.readString();
        truth = truth && checkWordCouple(word1,word2);
        word2 = word1; 
    }
```

Although now if given a single word, it will produce `true`.  This may be an improvement, but you’d need to check the exact requirements to be sure.

### Word Length

Is `HEAD`, `HEAL`, `TEA`, `TO` a word chain?  Your program says it is!

What about `HEAD`, `HEAL`, `HEALTHY`?  That input causes your program to crash!

Your program should handle mismatched word length, unless the problem statement guarantees all inputs will be the same length.

### Number of Differences

The problem description says:

> In a word chain, adjacent words must differ in **exactly** one letter

but `HEAD`, `HEAD`, `HEAD`, `HEAD` is reported as "true".  Clearly, `counter > 1` is not the correct "false" condition.  Borrowing Doi9t's suggestion, and further improving it, the correct line would read:

```
return counter == 1;
```

## Self Documenting Code

You read `word1`, then `word2`, and compare the first to the second (let’s call that “forward”), then read a third into `word1`, and compare the third to the second (comparison in the “reverse” direction).  You are testing for one difference, so it works, but what if you were checking for one additional character?  By reversing the word order, you’d actually be testing for character removal!

Instead of `word1` & `word2`, maybe `previous_word` and `next_word` would help keep things clearer.

```
    String previous_word = StdIn.readString();
    boolean truth = true;
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
    {
        String next_word = StdIn.readString();
        truth = truth && checkWordCouple(previous_word, next_word);
        previous_word = next_word; 
    }
```

Comment: I checked my program with "Head Tea To" and "Head Heal Healthy" and it produces error. Could you please explain more? Do you mean that I should add exception handling to produce meaningful errors?

Comment: Sorry. "HEAD HEAL TEA TO" will incorrectly produce "true" not crash; forgot the first two words are compared in a different order from the rest.  No — I wouldn't add exception handling.  But I would add do something differently in `checkWordCouple`.  You get the length of `word1`, and then blindly assume `word2` is the same length.  Perhaps you could check that?  Would it make sense to return `false` if they don't match?

Comment: I think so, if word1.length() != word2.length() it should return false.

Comment: Great review, one question. Any reason why suggesting to use `previous_word` instead of `previousWord`? Given that OP is already using camel case.

Comment: @Marc Certainly: I'm posting from an iPhone, and keeping track of everything in my head while posting is hard.  Ok, perhaps not the best of reasons...

Answer (score 6):

I have some suggestions for your code.

### Simplify the boolean conditions.

Generally, when you are returning both `true` and `false` surrounded by a condition, you know you can refactor the logic of the expression.

```java
if (counter > 1) return false;
else             return true;
```

can be changed into

```java
return counter <= 1;
```

By changing the range, we can make the condition shorter.

---

```java
boolean truth = true && checkWordCouple(word1,word2);
```

can be changed into

```java
boolean truth = checkWordCouple(word1,word2);
```

The `and` operator is useless (`true && false == false` and `true && true == true`) and is equivalent to a single boolean given by the `checkWordCouple` method.

### Use the simplified operator when possible.

**EDIT: As stated in the comments of this answer, the use of the Bitwise AND assignment operator is not recommended in this case.**

> Java gives you plenty of
> [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)
> to do multiple operations.
>
> In your case, you can use the `Bitwise AND assignment operator` (`&=`)
> instead of reassigning the boolean each time with the result of `ruth && checkWordCouple(word1,word2)`. `java truth = truth && checkWordCouple(word1,word2);`
>
> into
>
> `java truth &= checkWordCouple(word1,word2);`
>
> This operator will assign itself the result of the `previous value && current`.

Comment: I agree with "simplifying the boolean conditions", but replacing the **logical** *and* `&&` with the **bitwise** *and* assignment `&=` sounds like a mistake.

Comment: The bitwise will only be false when the `checkWordCouple` method return false and the value will be kept until the end of the loop (any false value found in the loop, and the final condition will stay false until the end). I don’t think this is a mistake, since both of the results will be similar. `truth = truth && checkWordCouple(word1,word2)` == `truth &= checkWordCouple(word1,word2);` [15.22.2. Boolean Logical Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)

Comment: @Stef Both the bitwise-and (`&`) and logical-and (`&&`) can be used with `boolean` values in Java. However, when bitwise-and is used, it does not perform short-circuit evaluation. `false && checkWordCouple(word1, word2)` will never call `checkWordCouple()`, where as `false & checkWordCouple(word1, word)` will always call it, as will `truth &= checkWordCouple(word1, word2);`, so `&&` should be preferred if the call has no side-effects to optimize performance.

Comment: Totally forgot about the `short-circuit`, my bad.

Comment: Other than playing Code-Golf, using the binary operators with `boolean` values doesn't have much value ... with the exception of xor.  There is no logical-xor operator (`^^`), but the binary-xor operator (`^`) does work with `boolean`.  There is no short-circuit evaluation possible for xor, so making the single character, non-short-circuiting `^` operator work for `boolean` values, is perhaps the justification for also allowing `&` and `|` to work.